# Show that there is a mapping $ S \ $ such that $ \ S^{-1} AS =\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} \ $

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \ $  and has repeated eigen value $ \lambda \ $. Let $ \vec u \ $ be the only Eigen vector associated with $ \lambda \ $ .

Show that there is a mapping $ S  \ $ such that $ \ S^{-1} AS =\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} \ $

**Answer:**

Since $ \lambda \ $ is repeated Eigen value and $ \vec u \ $ is  the only Eigen vector , we can find another Eigen independent  vector in the following way :

$ |A-\lambda I| \vec v=\vec u \ $

i.e., $ A \vec v=\vec u+\lambda \vec v \ $

Let $ S=[ \  \vec u \ | \  \vec v  \ ] \ $ be a matrix consisting of the Eigen vectors .

I think  $ S^{-1} AS=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}  \ $   **but I can not prove it** .

**Is there any help proving this ?**

Comment: I'm guessing you're not allowed to assume that every matrix has a Jordan Normal Form? That would make the question straight forward.

Comment: This matrix $ A $ will have Jordan canonical form because only one Eigen vector is associated with eigen value $ \lambda $ , i.e., geometric multiplicity of $ \lambda =1$

Comment: we have to prove  for some linear map $ S $ , $ \ S^{-1} AS=[\lambda \ \ 1 ; \ 0 \ \ \lambda ] \ $

Comment: Exactly, so the JNF will have to consist of only a single Jordan Block, since otherwise $\lambda$ would have geometric multiplicity of $2$. Thus, $A$ is similar to the given matrix.

Comment: but how to prove mathematically

Comment: What I'm saying is, you could cite the theorem that gives you this basically for free. Every matrix is similar to a JNF matrix. The fact that the $2 \times 2$ matrix has one eigenvalue and it has a $1$ dimension eigenspace tells you that the JNF matrix is the matrix you want. QED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $S$ you've constructed is a change of basis matrix $M(I, B, B_{\mathrm{st}})$, where $B = (\vec{u}, \vec{v})$ and $B_{\mathrm{st}}$ is the standard basis. Then
$$S^{-1} = M(I^{-1}, B_{\mathrm{st}}, B) = M(I, B_{\mathrm{st}}, B).$$
If we interpret $A = M(T, B_{\mathrm{st}}, B_{\mathrm{st}})$ for some operator $T$, then,
$$S^{-1} A S = M(I, B_{\mathrm{st}}, B)M(T, B_{\mathrm{st}}, B_{\mathrm{st}})M(I, B, B_{\mathrm{st}}) = M(T, B, B).$$
The columns of this matrix are computed by considering $[T\vec{u}]_B$ and $[T\vec{v}]_B$, which yield the columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is exact proof, but I just wanted to play with it. 
Why not insert the Eigen-decomposition into the original form:

$$
\begin{align}
S^{-1}AS &= S^{-1}VUV^TS
\end{align}
$$
U is a diagonal, V is an orthonormal matrix. Then from orthogonality of V:
$$
\begin{align}
S^{-1}AS &= (V^TS)^{-1}UV^TS
\end{align}
$$
If we write $K = (V^TS)^{-1}$ and assume that it is also a real orthogonal matrix, i.e. $(V^TS)^{-1}=(V^TS)^{T}$, then:
$$
\begin{align}
S^{-1}AS &= KUK^T
\end{align}
$$
which means that if we select $S$ to be properly (orthonormal), then A can be reduced to a diagonal form (diagonalizable).

Would that lead you to some result?

Comment: Here's a problem: there's an implicit assumption here that $A$ is orthogonally diagonalisable (i.e. symmetric). This is not the case, as diagonalisable matrices must have the sum of dimensions of their eigenspaces sum to the dimension of the space ($2$), and the sum in this case is $1$.